# After some character column name is hiding in oledb

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

i am reading the excel using OleDbCommand, when i am reading the tables from excel the column name of the few fields getting hided.

[image]

[image: column name in datatable]

i used oledbdatareader also but i am facing the issue,how can i resolve the issue.

Comment: Column names are limited to 64 characters, as per https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2fb51d81-3d64-445f-806a-519861b561ba/c-net-oledb-excel-reading-column-name-truncated?forum=adodotnetdataproviders .

Comment: how can i increase that column character length

Comment: From @mjwill's link: "_No, 64 characters is the column name limit with respect to Access and the Jet database engine. **To work around this issue you would need to use Excel automation or a third-party data access provider.**_"